# Finding the inverse Laplace transform after solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I wanted to solve $y''+9y=sin(3x)$, where $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$ by doing a Laplace Transform.

Taking $L[y''+9y]=L[sin(3x)]$ gives $s^{2}F(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+9F(s)=\frac{3}{s^2+9}$

The initial values are both zero, and $F(s)$ can be factored out of the left-hand side, leaving :

$F(s)=\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}$ and I couldn't figure out how to inverse transform this, but I did see that it was similar to $L^{-1}[\frac{2a^3}{(s^2+a^2)^2}] = sin(at)-atcos(at)$ which might be helpful

So in the end, how do I do $L^{-1}[\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}]$?

Comment: You can use $\frac{s^2}{(s^2+a^2)^2}=\frac{1}{s^2+a^2}-\frac{a^2}{(s^2+a^2)^2}$

Comment: @Moo you're right, I really meant item 11. Thank you, I will make an edit now.

Comment: Clear. I just need to divide by 1/18 (2*3^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of selected [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we can see that:

$$\text{y}_\alpha\left(x\right):=\displaystyle\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{2\alpha^3}{\left(\text{s}^2+\alpha^2\right)^2}\right]_{\left(x\right)}=\sin\left(\alpha x\right)-\alpha x\cos\left(\alpha x\right)\tag1$$

Now, in your case we have:

$$\frac{3}{\left(\text{s}^2+9\right)^2}=\frac{1}{18}\cdot\frac{2\cdot3^3}{\left(\text{s}^2+3^2\right)^2}\tag2$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and nice use of the real Laplace symbol, which I couldn't find lol)

Comment: @AnthonyML You're welcome, I am glad that I could help you!